# Are there any anti-virus programs that have a bot that clicks email links?

Tags: email

Just started a new job, and it looks like we have some bots that are clicking every link in some % of e-mails. The problem is, I can verify that at least a few of these people are real.

The only possibilities I can think of are:
1. The person is OCD and clicks on every link (not likely, can test with invis link)
2. The email is hacked and someone installed a bot on it.
3. They have some sort of security software (these are financial firms), that clicks on every link in some e-mails.

Any ideas? We're trying to figure who to block. Is there anti-virus software that clicks every link?

Comment: There are email clients that will follow links to inspect them before displaying them to the user. What client is being used? What email server is being used? How are you determining that the links have been clicked? You provide very few details for us to help you.

Answer (score 4):

A number of anti-virus, anti-spam, and anti-phishing solutions work by visiting every link in an email and checking to see if the link leads to a suspicious-looking site.  Sometimes you can detect them by checking the user-agent, but more often, they imitate the user-agent of a well-known browser (typically Internet Explorer) to prevent malicious sites from detecting them.

Answer (score 0):

If the links lead to a http resource you can check the useragent field, maybe you'll find a common value for all suspicious mail clients.